# Как сохранить файл без возможности его подмены

Tags: веб-программирование, unity3d, хеширование, webgl, md5

Разработана виртуальная среда для выполнения комплекса лабораторных работ. Это веб-приложение созданное в Unity (webgl). Оно размещено на сайте курса. После выполнения работы, пользователь сохраняет результат в виде excel файла на свой компьютер, после чего, ему нужно отправить его на сайт. Каким образом можно проверять, не были ли результаты заимствованы одним студентом у другого, то есть, проверять файл на редактирование (файл содержит имя пользователя в первой строке таблицы, то есть её нужно изменить при попытке сдать чужую работу)?

Comment: а зачем скачивать файл? сохраните сразу данные на сервер

Comment: Если не хотите что бы данные подделывали, то просто не давайте к ним никакого доступа. Сама программа лабораторных работ должна знать кем она запущена и сразу все данные отправлять на сервер, причем желательно сразу после их образования, не накапливая. все накопление данных должно быть на сервере. Правда приложение у вас на JS и особой сложности посмотреть что и как он отправляет и написать другой скрипт, который отправит присланные другим студентом данные, нет. Так что возможно в него надо будет встраивать некоторые слои защиты (например регистрировать время появления данных).

Comment: А можно где-то хранить хэш-сумму (н-р md5 и, н-р, в имени файла) с ФИО и данными результата. Что-то изменят в файле - не совпадет с хэшем из имени файла